# onKeyDown is non responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, keyboard, material-ui

Using a `Material-UI` `Table` I have this:

```
<Table
 onKeyDown={event => console.log(event)}>
  <TableBody>
    ...
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

When I click on the table with my mouse and then begin clicking the up and down arrow keys nothing logs to the console. I've tried putting the `onKeyDown` on the `TableBody` as well as the overall parent `div` of my Application with no luck whatsoever.

help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your table is not focusable. So onKeyDown is never triggered.

You coud add tabIndex to make it focusable, but make sure you dont have other focusable elements inside or they will take priority.

```
<Table
 tabIndex='123'
 onKeyDown={event => console.log(event)}>
  <TableBody>
    ...
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, Material-UI `Table` does not have an `onKeyDown` prop, but, its [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/table/) do say that:

> Any other properties supplied will be spread to the root element
>   (native element).

Assuming that the "root element" is a `table`, then what you're missing is a `tabIndex` prop.

From a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887551/how-can-i-trigger-an-onkeydown-event-on-html-table-on-firefox):

> You need to set `tabindex` property (eg `tabindex="1"`) to some value, so
>   it can identify that this table is keyboard selectable. That allows
>   the keyboard event to be triggered.